# Setting a map data to Firestore map

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a method that creates a map with a certain length based on an int value. The map consists of int value which is the same as the I value in the loop and a boolean value which is always false.

```
    Future initialMap(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode, int totalDays) async{
    List<Map<int, dynamic>> days = List<Map<int, dynamic>>() ;
    int i =0;
      while(i<totalDays){
        days[i].addAll({i:false});
        i++;
      }
      return await users.document(user.uid).collection('myPackages').document(packageCode).setData({
        'DaysMap': days
    });
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
ion in 3,580ms.
E/flutter (26175): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (26175): #0      List._setIndexed (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:152:72)
E/flutter (26175): #1      List.[]= (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have is normal because you are trying to access a value in the table's nonexistent index.
The array "days" is initially empty but you try to access a value by doing: days [i], which normally returns an error.

Since I was not sure of what exactly you wanted to achieve (build a list of maps, or build a map), I create these snippets :

The snippet above creates a list of maps:

```
Future initialMap(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode, int totalDays) async{
    List<Map<int, dynamic>> days = List<Map<int, dynamic>>() ;
    int i =0;
    while(i<totalDays){
        days[i].addAll({i:false});
        i++;
    }
    return await users.document(user.uid).collection('myPackages').document(packageCode).setData({
        'DaysMap': days
    });
 }
```

Sample result : `[{0: false}, {1: false}, {2: false}, {3: false}, {4: false}, {5: false}, {6: false}, {7: false}, {8: false}, {9: false}, {10: false}, {11: false}, {12: false}, {13: false}, {14: false}]`

The snipped above creates a map:

```
Future initialMap(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode, int totalDays) async{
    Map<int, dynamic> days = Map<int, dynamic>() ;
    int i =0;
    while(i<totalDays){
        days[i].addAll({i:false});
        i++;
    }
    return await users.document(user.uid).collection('myPackages').document(packageCode).setData({
        'DaysMap': days
    });
 }
```

Sample result: `{0: false, 1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false, 6: false, 7: false, 8: false, 9: false, 10: false, 11: false, 12: false, 13: false, 14: false}`

Also, you should never add side effects to functions. I mean, this function is supposed to build a list of items, it should only build this list and nothing else, instead you could create another function named for example `updateUserPackage(user, data)` that saves the data of the map previously generated by `initialMap()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Steve; I actually think I am having a problem storing the generated map to a Firestore Map. I did exactly as you said and split the function into two but unfortunately it doesn't set the generated map to Firestore.

Comment: is there a way to store the generated map to map field in firestore?